# Tableview cellForRowAt indexPath not getting called after language switch in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, arabic-support

I have a table view which works properly on app launch. When I switch app language and tap on a calendar text, it calls a delegate method for filtering the data, sets a flag and tableview is reloaded. In table view delegate methods, I check the flag and gets the data from appropriate array. The array returns 1 after language switch, but then the `cellforRowAt indexPath` method is not getting called.

```
extension CalendarViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (isFilterActive) {
            return filteredData.count  // returns 1 but cellForRowAt is not getting called
        }
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarCell") as! CalendarCell
        cell.delegate = self
        // ...
    }

}

extension CalendarViewController: CalendarViewDelegate {
    func filterEvent(for date: Date) {
        isFilterActive = true
        var i = 0
        filteredData = []
        filteredImagesData = [:]
        for (idx, val) in data.enumerated() {
            var fromDate: Date?
            var toDate: Date?
            // ..
                filteredData.append(val)
                i = i + 1
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.eventTableView.reloadData()  // <-- filters and calls reload
        }
    }
}
```

The `DateViewControllerClass which displays`JTAppleCalendarView` is

```
class DateViewController: UIViewController {
    let delegate = JSDelegate.shared
    weak var calendarVCDelegate: CalendarViewDelegate?
    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        calendarVCDelegate = self.delegate.getCalendarViewDelegate()
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

extension DateViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate, JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {
    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
        guard let dateCell = cell as? DateCell else { return }
        if (cellState.dateBelongsTo == .thisMonth) {
            dateCell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            dateCell.selectedView.isHidden = false
        }
        self.calendarVCDelegate!.filterEvent(for: date)  // <- calls delegate method on date cell tap
    }
}
```

I have wired `delegate` and `datasource` in storyboard. I have other filters and if I did to choose them before language switch, only then the table reload works. How to fix this?

Comment: Did you check whether your numberofrows method is getting called or not ?

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is getting called.

Comment: So did you check what is the value returned from there and the value of isFilterActive ?

Comment: Both are as expected. It returns `1` and flag as `true`.

Comment: That is strange, are you setting the delegate or datasource nil from anywhere in the code? If not can you please share an example project with the same issue to check, because I'm not seeing any other possible scenarios in your code which can cause this issue.

Comment: I am not setting nil from anywhere. I printed delegate and datasource values, they are not nil. I won't be able to share the project.

Comment: cross check the tableview constraint also

Comment: call only `self.eventTableView.reloadData()` outside of `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: I tried with and without that block, but it did not work

Comment: Give hard coded numberOfRowsInSection like 2, and then test same scenario, if it calls cellForRowAt or not.

Comment: This might be a bug in Xcode. Try setting the delegate methods not as extensions but rather in the original class declaration. I've run into the same issue a few weeks ago and this is what I did. I'm sorry if this doesn't help, but other commenters seemed puzzled too and this is the only thing I could think of.

Comment: I tried setting it 2 and it does not work. I also moved all extension methods to main class, but it did not solve.

Comment: What about `numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` when `isFilterActive  == true`? Are you returning > 0 ?

Comment: By default it returns 1, I hardcoded 2. The tableview shows content from the initial load, but when the filter is applied, the reload does not work. So the filtered content is not being visible. It shows the whole content.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a different object for the tableview or so. Not very clear. I solved it by using the following method.

Instead of calling `self.eventTableView.reloadData()` in the extension method, I post an notification `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Constants.AppNotification.EventTableViewShouldReload, object: self)`. The observer is added in the `viewDidLoad()` as `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Constants.AppNotification.EventTableViewShouldReload, object: nil, queue: nil, using: eventTableViewShouldReload)` with method:

```
@objc func eventTableViewShouldReload(notif: Notification) {
    print("reload data notif \(CalendarModel.filteredData.count)")
    CalendarModel.isFilterActive = true
    self.eventTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I created a data model class to hold static variables, without which the variables are getting cleared.

```
struct CalendarModel {
    static var data:[[String:Any]] = []
    static var filteredData:[[String:Any]] = []
    static var imagesData:[Int:UIImage] = [:]
    static var filteredImagesData:[Int:UIImage] = [:]
    static var isFilterActive = false
}
```

Now when the table view reloads it works properly. Without the `CalendarModel` static variables, I get the following log

```
reload data notif 1
numberOfRowsInSection 1
reload data notif 0  <-- called twice
numberOfRowsInSection 0  <-- second one, the filteredData.count is getting 0
cellForRowAt
configureCell
```